# angular-cli lower version locally

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, systemjs

I have a recent version of angular-cli installed globally.
The version is as follows.

```
C:\Users\W055013\kumar\learn\rx>ng --version
As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".


                             _                           _  _
  __ _  _ __    __ _  _   _ | |  __ _  _ __         ___ | |(_)
 / _` || '_ \  / _` || | | || | / _` || '__|_____  / __|| || |
| (_| || | | || (_| || |_| || || (_| || |  |_____|| (__ | || |
 \__,_||_| |_| \__, | \__,_||_| \__,_||_|          \___||_||_|
               |___/
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
```

Recently I started to experiment with ng2-ngrx-store. 
So I downloaded a few sample applications. 
When I try to build them I get the following errors:

```
 C:\Users\W055013\kumar\learn\rx\staffer\staffer-ng2-ngrxstore>ng build
    As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
    which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
    shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".


It seems like you're using a project generated using an old version of the Angular CLI.
The latest CLI now uses webpack and has a lot of improvements including a simpler
workflow, a faster build, and smaller bundles.

To get more info, including a step-by-step guide to upgrade the CLI, follow this link:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14
```

One solution is to migrate the sample applications to the recent version of angular-cli. However I do not want to do that as I just want to learn ng2-ngrxstore.

So, my question is ... can I install a lower version of angular-cli locally so that I can run the sample application. If yes , how ? if no can I get ngrxstore sample applications with the new angular-cli version somewhere....

Thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 10):

You can use the angular-cli version that is a dev-dependency for the specific project by using npm "scripts"

When you run 'ng serve' from command line, it uses your global package. But if you add a "script" to "package.json" of each application, "start":"ng serve" and run 'npm start' this will actually use the local angular-cli ( in that project's node_modules folder)

I believe that "start" scripts is default in angular-cli applications

Comment: Check out darrhal's comment at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5955 if unclear

Answer (score 2):

do npm start on your project which is equivalent to  ng serve. it will run your local angular version.

Answer (score 0):

Use NPX. Example of generating Angular project with version 5.0.0:
`npx -p @angular/cli@5.0.0 ng new projectName`

After installing, the CLI will continue to use your local version.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below way to lower down the version

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@version_number
For example: npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.19-4
```

To check the version

```
ng -v
```

Comment: my question was about having a different version gloablly and locally. is it possible?

And also I could not install a old lower version globally too. It suggests a list of recent lower versions to be installed as follows:
 C:\Users\W055013\kumar\learn\rx\staffer>npm install -g pm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.5
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 1.0.0-beta.32.3, 1.0.0-beta.32.2, 1.0.0-beta.32, 1.0.0-beta.31, 1.0.0-beta.30, 1.0.0-beta.29, 1.0.0-beta.28.3